# Use SparkSession.sql() with JDBC

Tags: mysql, scala, apache-spark, jdbc

**Problem :**

I would like to use JDBC connection to make a custom request using spark.

The goal of this query is to optimized memory allocation on workers, because of that I can't use :

```
ss.read
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql:dbserver")
  .option("dbtable", "schema.tablename")
  .option("user", "username")
  .option("password", "password")
  .load()
```

**Currently :**

I am currently trying to run :

```
ss = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName(appName)
  .master("local")
  .config(conf)
  .getOrCreate()

ss.sql("some custom query")
```

**Configuration :**

```
url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/database_name
driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
user=user_name
password=xxxxxxxxxx
```

**Error :**

```
[info] Exception encountered when attempting to run a suite with class name: db.TestUserProvider *** ABORTED ***
[info]   org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table or view not found: users; line 1 pos 14
[info]   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42)
[info]   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$lookupTableFromCatalog(Analyzer.scala:459)
[info]   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$anonfun$apply$8.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:478)
[info]   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$anonfun$apply$8.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:463)
[info]   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$resolveOperators$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:61)
[info]   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$resolveOperators$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:61)
[info]   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
[info]   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperators(LogicalPlan.scala:60)
[info]   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:58)
[info]   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:58)
```

**Assumption :**

I guess there is a configuration error, but I can't find out where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark can *read* and *write* data to/from relational databases using the JDBC data source (like you did in your first code example).

In addition (and completely separately), spark allows using SQL to query *views* that were created over data that was already loaded into a DataFrame from some source. For example:

```
val df = Seq(1,2,3).toDF("a") // could be any DF, loaded from file/JDBC/memory...
df.createOrReplaceTempView("my_spark_table")
spark.sql("select a from my_spark_table").show()
```

Only "tables" (called views, as of Spark 2.0.0) created this way can be queried using `SparkSession.sql`.

If your data is stored in a relational database, Spark will have to read it from there first, and only then would it be able to execute any distributed computation on the loaded copy. Bottom line - we can load the data from the table using `read`, create a temp view, and then query it:

```
ss.read
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("url", "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/database_name")
  .option("dbtable", "schema.tablename")
  .option("user", "username")
  .option("password", "password")
  .load()
  .createOrReplaceTempView("my_spark_table")

// and then you can query the view:
val df = ss.sql("select * from my_spark_table where ... ")
```

Comment: Your answer is very clear. When you load() the schema.tablename. Is the table entirely loaded into the workers memory ?

Comment: Not immediately - like most other Spark operations, `load` is _lazy_ - it wouldn't actually read any data until it needs to; So, for example, if the only use of the resulting view will contain some filter (e.g. `select .. where col1 = X`), that filter will be "pushed down" to MySQL so that only the records that match the filter will be loaded. Read more here: https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/sql-databases.html#push-down-optimization